# Clean up private static variables between unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, private, .net-core-3.1

I have a class that looks similar to this:

```
public class DiscoveryDocumentCache
{
    static DiscoveryDocumentCache()
    {
        cache = new MemoryCache(discoveryDocumentCacheName);
    }

    private static MemoryCache cache;

    // Other stuff...
}
```

I want the memory cache to be static so that it is shared across all instances of the class.

It is working great for the actual use cases.  Where I am struggling is with my unit tests.  Because the `cache` variable is static, it accumulates all the different values that get put in it.

My use case does not have a "remove" option.  (They just expire out of the cache.)

I have added this to my `DiscoveryDocumentCache` class:

```
    public void __UnitTesting__CleanUpMemoryCacheBetweenTests()
    {
        cache.Dispose();
        cache = new MemoryCache(discoveryDocumentCacheName);
    }
```

But it feels dirty to add a method that is just to facilitate unit testing.

.NET Framework had some ways to access class's private variables if you really thought you should.  **Is there something similar I can do to reset this static variable in my `TearDown` unit test method?**

Comment: Personally I'd shy away from a static object. Maybe inject a cache factory of some sort that gives you a cache object that may or may not be a singleton/static/whatever. Then you get to manually inject into your testable objects a cache object of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'll think this is an answer, or just a long comment. :-)

Your tests are working well because they are telling you something. They're saying "This is a bad use of a static instance."

Statics are always suspicious, although not always bad. What's bad here is you use a static to implement the singleton pattern in a way that is subsequently out of your control. That is, your individual instances are deciding for themselves which cache (the singleton) to use, rather than being told what to use.

As @Vaccano suggests, you are better off to use some sort of dependency injection. Translate that to "Tell each object what cache to use rather than having them figure it out for itself." This is one of those things that requires a bit of up-front investment in order to avoid saving trouble later.

As an aside... there is nothing wrong with changing your application to make it more testable. Testability is just another of those "ilities" that define good software design. The trick is to change it so as to improve the software, usually simplifying it rather than complicating it.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem with a static holding a value cached from file. It was being preserved between unit tests so I wanted to clear it, but that is not valid behaviour for the application as a whole.
Your answer pointed me in the right direction: changing another public property should trigger a nullification of the cached value, ready to be reloaded based on the new value of the public property.